# Add XY coordinates same values as Latitude Longitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, latitude-longitude, xy

I tried adding XY coordinates to longitude and latitude values I created in a csv file, and got to the point of having the csv converted to shapefile and in the correct coordinate system. I didn't manage to do it through Add XY Coordinates from Data Management, but doing it manually by adding geometry as someone suggested on another thread. The problem is that the output coordinates are the same as the latitude and longitude values
[image]

and I would bviously need the data in the format:
[image]

Is there any major mistake I might be doing? And is it possible to somehow calculate or find out the coordinates manually, if this cannot be resolved?

**Edit:**
I tried editing that section as you said, and I tried changing the datum or default coordinates system so much that I don't remember how many edits I did, but it still gives me the same values. At this point, I would like to ask if anyone knows how to find out what to add in the "origins" section in this convertor to get the values manually. I only have aroound 20 values, but I still have 100 problems as I don't have much knowledge about the program and its usage. s16.postimg.org/mhnskbqh1/image.jpg

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/209121/edit) your question (don't add as a comment) to specify what coordinate system you wish to output your X,Y values as.

Answer (score 1):

The Add XY Coordinates tool pays attention to the geoprocessing environment setting, "output coordinate system". If your desired output coordinate reference system uses a different geographic coordinate reference system than the data's, you would also want to set a default geographic transformation. That's located in the same section in the geoprocessing environment--Output Coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but it appears that you need to set the output coordinate system to a GEOGRAPHIC COORDINATE SYSTEM,  not a PROJECT COORDINATE SYSTEM.  Arcmap has taken your longitude and latitude values and used them as metres in a projected coordinate system.

Open ArcMap, go to dataframe properties, coordinate system tab, select a Geographic Coordinate System, likely WGS84:

[image]

Once you have done that you can add your points manually, or go to the catalog and right click on your table, select 'Create Features from XY Table':

[image]

You must select a geographic coordinate system for your input file:

[image]

You can then project the output file to whatever coordinate system you need and then calculate the X and Y as metres (or whatever unit).